# Reg command in Stata using indices

Tags: stata

I want to run the following regression in Stata

```
reg y x1 x2 x3 ... x100
```

I'm looking for a quick way to rewrite the above command through indices that does not require to explicitly write each x1, x2, x3, ..., x100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
reg y x1-x100
```

Comment: This will be correct if and only if `x1-x100` matches the order of the variables in memory. It won't be essential to have `x1 x2` ... `x99 x100` so long as all the others are somewhere between `x1` and `x100`. In principle, there could be other variables in between somehow, so watch out. Also find out about wildcards, e.g. `x*`.